# Nativescript webview crash on load after Google maps: How do I software render a webview?

Tags: android, nativescript

As the title states, I have a webview in my app and it runs fine - unless I load the other page with a Google map on it first.

I did find a partial answer to this which states it's possible to work around by software rendering the webview: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35450929/2145126

I'm seeing the crash on my Pixel_2_API_28 emulator, which means if it is the same bug, it's not limited to the hardware the answer listed. It runs fine on my physical phone (LG Velvet)

I'd like to try the software rendering solution, but can't figure out how to do that in Nativescript.

Edit to clarify: I am using nativescript-google-maps-sdk. The linked answer states that loading 2d canvas objects before a webview on certain phones/sdk levels on Android will cause a crash unless you put the webview into software rendering mode. My question is specifically how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

use a native component like https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/ or https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@nativescript-community/ui-mapbox/
follow the install instructions of their readme's.
if the content of a webview is to heavy, it can cause an app crash

Comment: I updated my question to clarify, I am using a native component.If you read the link in my question I think the issue becomes more clear.